# How can you copy from subdirectories in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, copy

Suppose I have the following folder structure:

```
folder
  -subfolderA
    -module1.mod
      -module1.a
      -module1.b
      -module1.c
    -module2.mod
      -module2.a
      -module2.b
      -module2.c
    -module1.d
  -subfolderB
    -module3.mod
      -module3.a
      -module3.b
      -module3.c
    -module3.d
```

I'd like to flatten away just the "subfolder" tier of directories, producing the following:

```
outputFolder
  -module1.mod
    -module1.a
    -module1.b
    -module1.c
  -module2.mod
    -module2.a
    -module2.b
    -module2.c
  -module3.mod
    -module3.a
    -module3.b
    -module3.c
  -module1.d
  -module3.d
```

I expected this to be extremely simple, with:

```
copy {
    from "folder/*/"
    into "outputFolder"
}
```

But this didn't work.  What's the easiest way to flatten away one (or more) layers of subdirectories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually settled on the following as the best combination of clean and configurable.  By modifying n, you can flatten as many directories as you like:

```
copy {
    from {
        file("folder")
        include "**/*"
        eachFile { file ->
            file.relativePath = new RelativePath(true, file.relativePath.segments.drop(n))
        }
        includeEmptyDirs = false
    }
    into "outputFolder"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do it as

```
copy {
    from 'folder' 
    include '*/**/*.*' 
    eachFile { FileCopyDetails fcd ->
        int slashIndex = fcd.path.indexOf('/')
        fcd.path = fcd.path.substring(slashIndex+1)
    } 
    into "outputFolder"
}
```

Or perhaps

```
copy {
   from { file('folder').listFiles().findAll { it.directory } } 
   into "outputFolder"
}
```